# How can I do an if conditional for a failure of a bash command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, scripting

I'd like to have a very simple condition that will only execute if the `command` fails.

In this example it's a conditional based on the SUCCESS of the command.

```
if command ; then
    echo "Command succeeded"
fi
```

**I'd like the opposite** - how can I do this? Is there a elagant way besides doing a comparison on `$?`

I do not want to use the `||` or operator - it does semantically convey (in my opinion) the desired functionality. In the case of `command || echo "command failed"`.

Comment: Related: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/65304)

Comment: You may find examples in this thread useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/512770/what-is-use-of-command-command<br>
`command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Negate the command’s exit status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#index-_0021):

```
if ! command ; then
    echo "Command failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to @StephenKitt's correct answer: use the `:` "no-op" command in the "then" block and the `else` block:

```
if command; then :; else
    echo "command failed"
fi
```

Full disclosure: I would not use this method myself.

Comment: That's what you had to use in the Bourne shell which didn't have the `!` keyword (added in ksh88e and bash in 1.11 or before)